# Weight regularisation in CNN

Tags: conv-neural-network, regularization, overfitting, ridge-regression

I am trying to understand the concept of weight regularisation in CNN. I know that in dense layer with weight $w$ it corresponds to finding:
$$
\mathbf{w}^{*}=\underset{\mathbf{w}}{\arg \operatorname{min} }\left\{\frac{1}{2 N} \sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_{i}-f_{\mathbf{w}}\left(x_{i}\right)\right)^{2}+\frac{\lambda}{2} \sum_{j} w_{j}^{2}\right\}
$$

Where we have used the MSE as loss function and the $L^2$ regularizer. Is the definition for CNN equivalent?, i.e:
$$
\mathbf{K}^{*}=\underset{\mathbf{K}}{\arg \operatorname{min} }\left\{\frac{1}{2 N} \sum_{i=1}^{N}\left(y_{i}-f_{\mathbf{K}}\left(x_{i}\right)\right)^{2}+\frac{\lambda}{2} \|K\|^{2}\right\}
$$

Where $K$ is the filter of the CNN

Comment: yep, it's the same

Comment: Thank you @shimao. Do you have any reference?